# css icon without image

Tags: html, css, unicode, emoji, icon-fonts

How are icons / images shown (, ,  ) which appear to be a `normal` character (as if i would enter b,d,r)

```html
<p>
<span data-preserver-spaces="true">
If your team is a bit more "fun", you can always give these alternate signals a shot: 
✨ (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">feat</span>), 
 (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">fix</span>), 
 (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">docs</span>), 
 (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">style</span>), 
♻️ (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">refactor</span>), 
 (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">perf</span>), 
✅ (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">test</span>), 
 (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">build</span>), 
 (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">ci</span>), 
 (<span style="font-family: 'andale mono', 'lucida console';">chore</span>).
</span>
</p>
```

In case it does not render on every browser i copied the code above to [this codepen](https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/eYbLYwO) and attach this screenshot here

[image: Icons]

### Question

- How does it work?
- Is there a (built in?!) font and are these icons some UTF-* or hex-codes?

[not relevant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhM3q.png)

Comment: the link is not related to the question.

Comment: Link removed as implied in the comment from Lelio Faieta.

Comment: They are Unicode characters, and the fonts have to deal with them of course, that's why you sometimes encounter an empty rectangle or a question mark instead of the actual icon. You can play around [with this tool](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) that tells you what character is it

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tool - see update above.

Comment: Robin do you want to create an answer so that the question is no longer unanswered?

Comment: @surfmuggle done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are all Unicode characters, and the fonts have to deal with them of course, that's why you sometimes encounter an empty rectangle or a question mark instead of the actual icon. You can play around with [this tool](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) that tells you what character is it.

The tool [balestone](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) returns the unicode for a given input.

[image: bug_books_rocket]

Pasting in the characters for bug, books, rocket (  ) resulted in

```
U+1F41B : BUG
U+1F4DA : BOOKS
U+1F680 : ROCKET
```

Comment: Do you know what font is missing if only a rectangle is displayed? How is the font "connected" to the Unicode character?

Comment: @surfmuggle — you have it backwards. The font in use is missing that particular character. There isn’t one font per character.

Comment: @Quentin understood. If the font must  have a representation of a certain unicode (like in this case `bug == U+1F41B`) how is the connection between a certain character to a certain font (a [OpenType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff) font file). Or in other words the bug icon (?? glyph ??) that is rendered for the unicode character `U+1F41B` could look different on another OS using another font file?

Comment: There are whole websites dedicated to comparing the default emoji on different systems.